# how should I show that list chromatic number of $K_{3,3}=3$?

Tags: graph-theory

how should I show that list chromatic number of $K_{3,3}=3$?

I have no efficient tool for proving this kind of question,what should I do?

please give me hint,ideas or reference to study.thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps this helps? http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Some_choosability_numbers_for_the_complete_bipartite_graph

Comment: thanks,it really helps!thanks a lot!