# A graph with list chromatic number $4$ and chromatic number $3$

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, coloring

What is an example of a graph with chromatic number $\chi(G)=3$ and list-chromatic number $\chi_\ell(G)=4$?

My first thought was to consider complete tripartite graphs since these will have chromatic number $3$. I also know that [$K_{3,3}$ has list chromatic number $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978050/how-should-i-show-that-list-chromatic-number-of-k-3-3-3), so tried (without success) to find a $3$-list-assignment for $K_{3,3,1}$ which was not colourable.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [list coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) has an example showing $K_{3,27}$ has list chromatic number $4$, and by properties bipartite graphs have chromatic number $2$.  Perhaps you would be able to modify that example.  In general, it shows $K_{q,q^q}$ has list chromatic number at least $q+1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I guess $K_{3,27}+K_3$ would be the easiest way to get what the OP wants by modifying that example. The construction in my answer below produces a somewhat smaller example, $19$ vertices instead of $30$; I have no idea if it's the smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with chromatic number $2$ and list chromatic number $3,$ e.g. $G=K_{3,3},$ or just take $C_6$ and add an edge joining two diametrically opposite vertices.

Take the graph $3G$ (the union of three vertex-disjoint copies of $G$); add a new vertex $v$ and edges joining $v$ to every vertex of $3G.$ You can easily show that the resulting graph has chromatic number $3$ and list chromatic number $4.$

Comment: Thanks, I see how the modification to $K_{3,3}$, call it $H$, has chromatic number $3$ -- is there an easy way to show chromatic number $4$? I can show $\chi_\ell(H)>3$, but I'm not aware of a theorem/method to put an upper bound on it. Do I just need to start with "let $L$ be an arbitrary $4$-list assignment..." and show that it works?

Comment: Let $L$ be an arbitrary $4$-list assignment. Colour the new vertex first . . .

Comment: Ah of course, just remove $c(v)$ from each list in $3G$ (or an arbitrary colour, if $c(v)$ is not in some list), and the problem is reduced to a $3$-list assignment on $G$ which we know can be coloured.

Comment: Sorry to hijack but why does three copies of $K_{3, 3}$ force the list chromatic number to be greater than three? I imagine the idea is that each copy of $K_{3,3}$ can be assigned a colouring such that one colour must appear in this colouring, and then we assign $v$ the three colours corresponding to the "must appear" colours from each of the three copies of $K_{3,3}$; however I can't seem to make this work on paper.

Comment: @D.P Let $G_1,G_2,G_3$ be three disjoint graphs of list chromatic number $3,$ e.g. three copies of $K_{3,3}.$ Assign lists of size $2$ to the vertices of $G_i$ so that $G_i$ can't be coloured from its lists. Add a new vertex $v$ and edges joining $v$ to each vertex of $G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3.$ Assign three new colours $c_1,c_2,c_3$ to $v,$ and add $c_i$ to the list of each vertex of $G_i.$ Now, whichever color is chosen for vertex $v,$ one of the graphs $G_i$ will be left with its old coloring.